# Rearranging Question

Tags: probability

Hi guys I have come to the following inequality but can't seem to workout how to get to my final step. I know it is just rearranging the equation but I haven't been able to get it or I would like someone to tell me if they think I need to start again.

$p_{j}+r_{j} p_{k} > p_{k}+r_{k}p_{j}$

where $r_i=(1-p_i-q_i) $

and I need to work it into the following

${p_{j}\over{p_{j}+q_{j}}} > {p_{k}\over{p_{k}+q_{k}}} $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\frac{p_{j}}{1-r_{j}}=\frac{p_{j}}{p_{j}+q_{j}}>\frac{p_{k}}{p_{k}+q_{k}}=\frac{p_{k}}{1-r_{k}}\iff p_{j}\left(1-r_{k}\right)>p_{k}\left(1-r_{j}\right)\iff p_{j}+r_{j}p_{k}>p_{k}+r_{k}p_{j}$

Comment: Thank you sir, wow I feel a bit embarrassed for asking in the first place. Have a nice day!

Comment: You are very welcome. Have a nice day too in which your embarassment will gradually flow away :).